# Nodejs server sends bad encoded files as response to GET call

Tags: node.js, reactjs, api, file

I want to send files from my nodejs server as response to an api GET call.

In the nodejs server, this is the snippet that does the file sending for the GET call:

```
       fs.readFile(localPath, function (err, data ) {
   
        res.set('Content-Type','application/octet-stream');
        res.set('Content-Disposition',`attachment; filename=${req.query.fileName}`);
        res.set('Content-Length',data.length);  //data.length - 1 ?

        var response = res.status(200).send(data);

        //delete file
        //fs.unlinkSync(localPath);

        return response;

    });
```

and in my front end, I make the GET call like this :

```
  const handleDownloadFile = () => {

     const fileNameWithoutMarker = message.attributes.content.replace("azure510-", "")

     axios.get("/api/azure-download?fileName=" + fileNameWithoutMarker).then(resp => {
       fileDownload(resp.data, `${fileNameWithoutMarker}`);
     }).catch(error => {
         console.log(error)
     }); 

}
```

The file gets downloaded, but it has bad encoding, and cannot be used. If I want to open the file from my server folder, it works. Only when is send by the nodejs server, the encoding is messed up.

Does anyone has any suggestion on how to try to fix this ? Or how can I debug it ?

Comment: There are always two parties involved: the sender and the receiver. There is also a chance something goes wrong within `fileDownload()` have you tried executing this particular request in Postman?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `js-file-download` documentation specifies:

> When downloading binary data, the data must be a Blob, otherwise the
> downloaded file will be corrupted.

By default, it seems that axios tries to parse `octet-stream` response body types as text.
Try to set the axios `responseType` option to `blob` and see if it works better.

```
axios.get("/download", { responseType: "blob" })
```

Comment: maan, you saved me !!